Can not change ISCSI disk mount point to other directory
Problem: I can not change ISCSI disk mount point to other directory.
Currently I have ISCSI disk mounted to /iscsi2
I would like to change it to /iscsi
I changed /iscsi2 to /iscsi in /etc/fstab, but mounting to /iscsi is unsuccessful.
Reproducing steps:

Mount /iscsi2 based on /etc/fstab. Failed, because mountpoint is already renamed to /iscsi
mount /iscsi2
mount: can't find /iscsi2 in /etc/fstab


Mount /iscsi2 based on device path, successful.
mount /dev/sdd1 /iscsi2


Shows that it is mounted:
lsblk -af | grep -i iscsi
L¦sdd1 ext4   ISCSI_Backup2    3829ed05-f445-425d-8213-3b1c2d41fba /iscsi2


Unmount /iscsi2:
umount /iscsi2


Shows that it is unmounted:
lsblk -af | grep -i iscsi
L¦sdd1 ext4   ISCSI_Backup2    3829ed05-f445-425d-8213-3b1c2d41fba


Mount /iscsi based on device path. Failed.
mount /dev/sdd1 /iscsi


Shows that it is still unmounted:
lsblk -af | grep -i iscsi
L¦sdd1 ext4   ISCSI_Backup2    3829ed05-f445-425d-8213-3b1c2d41fba



Any idea why mount is successful to /iscsi2 and fails to /iscsi ?

Which distribution are you using? Does it have additional security mechanisms such as SELinux or AppArmor in effect?

Using Debian 9 stretch

I hope your pay Freexian for their LTS subscription, otherwise your debian hasn't seen security updates in 4 years and 30 days; even the debian-owned LTS has been gone for more than 2 years. But that's likely to be unrelated to the problem at hand.

What is the actual error message for the unsuccessful mount? If you run fuser /iscsi2 as root, does it list any processes currently using the directory? If so, can you get rid of those processes?

@telcoM: fuser /iscsi2: empty result. lsof /iscsi2: empty result. lsof /iscsi: empty result.

No error message for the unsuccessful mount. It seems to be successful, but still not mounted.

@klor See if systemctl daemon-reload help, maybe.

@TomYan: Excellent! systemctl daemon-reload solved the misterious mount problem! Now mount /iscsi mounted the disk! Thank you very much! Please post it as solution!

In a systemd system, mount units, which systemd uses to keep track of mounts, are generated from fstab entries at boot. If the fstab is modified afterwards, the user is supposed to notify the system manager about it (with systemctl daemon-reload; certainly you can reboot as well) so that the mount units are updated accordingly.
(FYI, a user is really supposed to notify systemd for updates on any kind of units, including but not limited to service units or "handwritten" mount units.)
I am not sure what exactly happened behind the scene, but apparently having an outdated mount unit could end up causing the filesystem on the same device to unmount right away when the user attempts to mount it on a different mountpoint. (Not sure which version of systemd you are using; it might even be just a bug that has been fixed already in later versions.)
